# Trouble with a Radix sort function

Tags: c++, sorting, linked-list

In my program I am using a Radix Sort via Linked List to sort nine digit numbers, but for some reason it is not sorting correctly.

This is how I generate my numbers:

```
void genData(int *dta, int n) 
{
    // generate the numbers at random
    for(int i=0; i < n; i++)
        dta[i] =  rand()%889 + 111 + 1000*(rand()%889 + 111) + 1000000*(rand()%889 + 111);
}
```

This is the Radix Sort function:
The outer loop is run through 3 times. Once for each set of 3 digits.

```
int radixSort(int *dta, int n, int *out)
{ 
    // the dta array contains the data to be sorted.
    // n is the number of data items in the array
    // out is the array to put the sorted data

    node *bucket[1000]; 
    int count = 0; 
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)out[i] = dta[i]; 

    for (int pass = 0; pass < 3; pass++)  // outer loop
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 1000; j++) // set bucket[] to all zeroes (NULL) for each pass 
        {
            bucket[j] = NULL;
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) // inner loop -- walks through the out array (which contains the data to be sorted)
        {
            int index = 0; 
            int tmp = 0;
            switch(pass) 
            {
                case 0:
                    index = out[i] % 1000;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    tmp = out[i]/1000; // tmp = 123456
                    index = tmp%1000; // mid = 456// set index to the middle 3 digits
                    break;
                case 2:
                    tmp = out[i]/1000;  // set index to the first 3 digits
                    index = tmp/1000;
                    break;
            };

            //Create new head node if nothing is stored in location
            if(bucket[index] == NULL)           
            {   
                node *newNode = new node(0, bucket[0]); 
            }
            else
            {
                node *newNode =  new node(out[i], NULL); //Created new node, stores out[i] in it
                node *temp = bucket[index];
                while(temp->next != NULL) // finds the tail of the Linked List
                {
                    temp = temp->next;
                    count++; //For Big-O
                }
                temp->next = newNode;   // make tail point to the new node.
            }
            count++; //For Big-O
        } // end of the inner (i) loop

        int idx = 0; // for loading the out array
        for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)  // walk through the bucket
        {
            if(bucket[i] == NULL)continue; // nothing was stored here so skip to the next item

            // something is stored here, so it is put into the out array starting at the beginning (idx)
            out[idx++] = bucket[i]->data;

            if(bucket[i]->next->next != NULL || bucket[i]->next->next)
            // now see if there are more nodes in the linked list that starts at bucket[i]. If there are, put their data into out[idx++]
            {
                out[idx++] = bucket[i]->data;
            }
            count++; //For Big-O
        }


    }// end of the outer loop pass). The output (out) from this pass becomes the input for the next pass

    return count; // Again -- for Big-O 
}
```

I think that the problem might have to be with the new node that I create. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: looks like you forgot to set `bucket[index] = newNode;` during its first init

Comment: Would I do that right after creating `newNode`?

Comment: yes, check the answer below, it has sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic for storing a number in a linked list is not correct.

Here is a suggested outline:

- Always create a new node to store the number.
- Always set the `next` pointer of the new node to `NULL`.
- Find the end of the linked list at `bucket[index]`.

  - If there is no linked list at `bucket[index]` then you have already found the end.

    ```
    node *newNode = new node(out[i], NULL);
    if (bucket[index] == NULL)           
    {
        // there was no linked list there before; start one now.
        bucket[index] = newNode; 
    }
    else
    {
        // find tail of linked list and append newNode
        node *temp = bucket[index];
        while (temp->next != NULL)
        {
            temp = temp->next;
            count++; //For Big-O
        }
        temp->next = newNode;   // make tail point to the new node.
    }
    ```

EDIT: You already had a `while` loop that follows the linked list from its head to its tail.

To get the values out of the linked list, you also start at the head and then follow the list until you reach the tail.  But, as you visit each node in the list, you get out a value.

```
            if (bucket[i] == NULL)continue; // nothing was stored here so skip to the next item

            // if we reach this point there is at least one value stored here

            // get values out
            node *temp = bucket[i];
            out[idx++] = temp->data;
            while (temp->next != NULL)
            {
                temp = temp->next;
                out[idx++] = temp->data;
            }
```

But we can make this cleaner with a `do` / `while` loop.  You use a `do` / `while` when you want to do something at least once, and possibly more than once.  In this case, if we run this loop at all it is because we want to get out at least one number.  So:

```
            if (bucket[i] == NULL)continue; // nothing was stored here so skip to the next item

            // if we reach this point there is at least one value stored here

            // get values out
            node *temp = bucket[i];
            do
            {
                out[idx++] = temp->data;
                temp = temp->next;
            }
            while (temp != NULL);
```

It's cleaner to use a `do` / `while` loop, than to repeat the line that stores a value in `out`.

The loop can handle any length list other than length 0, and you already have the check with the `continue` to handle the case where there is no linked list in `bucket[i]`.

Comment: With that being changed, it seems to create an `Access Violation` (run-time error) for the line where I check for other nodes in the linked list that start at `bucket[i]`. `if(bucket[i]->next->next != NULL || bucket[i]->next->next)`. Any idea why that is happening now?

Comment: The expression `bucket[i]->next->next` will cause an error when the linked list is length 0 or length 1.  If `bucket[i]` is `NULL` you will get an error.  If `bucket[i]->null` is `NULL` you will also get an error.  It is always an error to apply the `->` operator to a `NULL` pointer.

Comment: You should use a `while` loop to follow the entries in the linked list.  The code you have now with `->next->next` is not correct.

Comment: I guess I put that because I don't really understand how to check for other nodes starting in the same location as `bucket[i]`

Comment: So use a `while` loop, but how do I check for that? ^

Comment: I'll modify the answer with a little more info.